# Create column from another table dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working with TSQL and C#. I have two queries that return strings:

```
string[] allSubcategories = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("SubcategoryName")).Distinct().ToArray();

   var redMark = db.GetTableBySQL("SELECT * FROM RedMarkItems");
string[] redMarkColumns = redMark.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

So, as you can see I have two different arrays, first I get subcategoriesNames:

[image]

and all columns of table RedMarkItems:

[image]

That I want to do is to create column dynamically, I mean, if subcategorieName does not exist as column in RedMarkItems do an Update and create it someting like:

```
  var createColumn = db.ExeSQL($"ALTER TABLE RedMarkItems ADD {ColumnName} BIT");
```

How can I compare if subcategorieName does not exist as column in RedMarkItems table? Then create column as my query? Regards

Comment: just do a foreach loop and compare? However this looks like a broken DB design to me. But hard to get to a conclusion without more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if a particular column exists in an already filled DataTable using the Linq approach then it is just:

```
bool exists = redMark.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName == "SubCategoryName");
```

Instead, if you want to ask this info directly to the database then use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) views The Columns view is the one to use with a query like this.

```
string query = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Column 
                           WHERE Column_Name = @colName) 
                    SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@colName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "SubCategoryName";
bool exists = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1);
```

Now, the part about creating the column is pretty simple as code per se. It is just an appropriate ALTER TABLE. But there are a lot of things to be cleared before. What will be the datatype of the new column? What will be its length and precision? What will be the constraints applied to it (Null/Not Null defaults etc)? As you can see all these info are very important and require to be defined somewhere in your code.